# How to show the following symmetric matrix is invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, symmetric-matrices

**Question**

(This is an updated version of a question I had asked before which remains unsolved). Say for any square matrix A with diagonal elements $a_{ii} =1$ and off-diagonal elements $a_{ij} \in (-1,0]$, for $j\neq i$. Matrix $B = A^TA$. So Matrix $B$ is symmetric. Matrix $C$ is defined as $2diag(B)+B$ which means that the diagonal elements of $B$ are multiplied by 3 while the off-diagonal by 1 (i.e. $c_{ii}=3b_{ii}, c_{ij}=b_{ij} \text{ for } j\neq i$). How do I show that $C$ is invertible?

I managed to solve the 2 by 2 case by comparing common terms in the determinant. But even a 3 by 3 matrix would make the comparison infeasible. Grateful for any comments and suggestions!

Comment: I haven't checked that this will work, but my initial guess is to try using Gershgorin's theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem to show that $0$ is not an eigenvalue of $C$. Again, I'm not totally sure that this is applicable, but it's worth checking out.

Comment: @Dave Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with Gershgorin's theorem. A quick read suggests that maybe a direct application could be related to diagonally dominant matrices. However, a numerical search rejects this approach. There are cases in which it is not diagonally dominant. Could you elaborate more on how this might be applied to this context to show that 0 is not an eigenvalue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you noted, $B$ is symmetric. Furthermore, it is positive semidefinite since $$x^TBx = x^TA^TAx = \|Ax\|_2^2\geq 0.$$ Define $D = \mathrm{diag}(B)$. Then for the matrix $C$, we have $$x^TCx = x^TBx + 2x^TDx = \|Ax\|_2^2 + 2\|D^{1/2}x\|_2^2\geq 2\min\{\sqrt{d_{ii}}\}\|x\|_2^2\geq \|x\|_2^2.$$ The last inequality comes from the fact that $d_{ii} = \|a_i\|_2^2\geq 1$. Furthermore, notice that equality only holds when $x=0$ since $d_{ii} = \|a_i\|_2^2\geq 1>0$. This inequality implies that $C$ has only positive eigenvalues. Indeed, let $v,\lambda$ be an eigenpair of $C$, then $$v^TCv = \lambda\|v\|_2^2>\|v\|_2^2\implies\lambda>0.$$ Here we used strict inequalities since $v\neq 0$ from the definition of an eigenvector.

Comment: @whpwell96 Thanks so much! This is really helpful. I just have one question regarding the inequality $\|A x\|_2^2+2\left\|D^{1 / 2} x\right\|_2^2 \geq\left(1+2 \min \left\{\sqrt{d_{i i}}\right\}\right)\|x\|_2^2$. How are we able to add the term $1$ on the RHS? Without it, I believe the proof is still valid. But I fail to see how we can establish that $\|A x\|_2^2 \geq\|x\|_2^2$ which I assume is how you introduced the term $1$ . Thanks, again, for your excellent answer!

Comment: Hello, that one was a  mistake. The post has been edited

Comment: Got it, thanks!